# In AngularJs SPA how do I remove the ".html" from my URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, location, single-page-application

I have been researching over this for some time now, have come across quiet a few stackoverflow discussions which are similar but none of which answer this question to my satisfaction. I am not sure if angularjs has a way to do this, but I am sure there is a way to do this when writing angularjs SPA applicaiton. Here goes my situation,

I am writing an AngularJs front end for an existing ASP.NET MVC based application. 
The URL in the current application look like

```
https://domain.com/login
https://domain.com/profile
https://domain.com/settings
```

etc

My new frontend version reads

```
https://domain.com/index.html/login
https://domain.com/index.html/profile
https://domain.com/index.html/settings
```

Problem I need with is,

I need to remove the .html from the  new urls. This is my first hurdle. Everything that I need to do later depends on how my URL reads. It needs to read in a format ASP.NET MVC provided. A url without the .html file extension in the URL.

When I googled for suggestions with keywords "angularjs url remove html and #!"

The top two results I get are

[How to remove index.html from url on website based on angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17699386/how-to-remove-index-html-from-url-on-website-based-on-angularjs)

and

[Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-symbol-from-angular-js-urls)

none of which are quiet helpful in solving my situation.

There is a workaround I am considering if there is no better way to do this, which would be

"Since Index.html is where my ng-view resides and essentially this page drives my SPA architecture, so I can do into my IIS and set Index.html as a default document" What this does is helps me achieve what I want (not show ".html" in the URL) to a certain extent. For example (when working locally) if I navigate to `http://localhost` it will open the index.html without the file name being displayed in the URL and the angularJs routing still works fine as long as I don't refresh or copy paste those URLs (without index.html in them) in which case I get 404 errors (when I use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to remove the #s).

This surely is not the ideal solution because when the system emails users with URLs they need to use to access certain parts of applicaiton, we will invariably need to include the index.html in there (which we do not want to)

Any help, extremely appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's server side problem, not cliend side. You must handle request from server side like this:

```
handle '/'
    return view 'index.html'
```

Then when you visit `https://domain.com/`, you will see `index.html` file, but it will not be visible in url.

**EDIT**

If you are using angular's html5 mode then you shall do more complex routing, something like this:

```
handle '/'
handle '/login'
handle '/profile'
handle '/settings'
    return view 'index.html'
```

Because for example you are on url: https://domain.com/profile and you refreshed the page, request will be sent to this url, so you shall also handle `'/profile'` route and return same `index.html` page (then angularjs will take care about routing)

If you are using hash(#) then when you refresh https://domain.com/#/profile page, request will be sent to https://domain.com/ and `'/'` route handler will be enough

Comment: Thanks Karaxuna. Unfortunately this is a purely front end framework driven by angularjs now (the new application) which consumes MVC WebApi based REST Services for a back end. There is no server side code to 'return views' (like we did with MVC web app or as you suggested)

Comment: You also have static file hosting server yes? Or is it ftp? You must handle request the way I said, there is no other way (As far as I know)

Comment: Also you will need more complex routing if you are using html5 mode on angularjs

Comment: "need more complex routing if you are using html5 mode" - Can you elaborate or suggest a post/online resource you are referring to?

Comment: Thanks a lot @karaxuna. I am gonna give this a try once I figure out where/how can I introduce server side routing in my app. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a URL Rewrite rule in your web.config :

```
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Registration" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^Registration"/>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/registration.html"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
```